# Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be integers satisfying $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. Prove: $abc$ must be even.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic

I'm pretty sure that this can be proved by reductio ad absurdum, and have a proof for that. However, I'm not sure how to prove this using any other method of proof. It's my first time taking a course in logic and I'm not sure where to go with this.

Comment: The only way in which $abc$ can be odd is that all the three of $a,b,c$ are odd. But in such a case, $c^2=a^2+b^2$ is even, so $c$ cannot be odd.

Comment: Also can show that $ab$ must even.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hint: Think about even and odd numbers. Can all 3 variables be odd?

Answer (score 0):

It can also be proven directly from a certain formula. The numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ are called "Pythagorean triples." Given two integers $m$ and $n$ satisfying $0 < m < n$, you can obtain a Pythagorean triple with this "recipe":

- $a = n^2 - m^2$
- $b = 2mn$
- $c = m^2 + n^2$

So $a$ and $c$ could be odd, but $b$ is even, and that's enough for $abc$ to be even as well. For example: $5^2 + 12^2 = 13^2$ and $5 \times 12 \times 13 = 780$.

Maybe you distrust the formula above. That's fine. It might be possible for both $a$ and $b$ to be odd. But then $a^2 + b^2$ is even. For example: $3^2 + 5^2 = 34$ (which is even, though it's not itself a square).

Comment: Not all triples are primitive, you may have to multiply by a constant

Comment: @qwr You're right, no pun intended. Let's say the constant is odd, say, 3. So from 5, 12, 13 we go to 15, 36, 39. One of the sides is still even.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution of this question.

Let show by induction that the relation among three sizes of the right triangle is $$k,\frac{k^2-1}{2},\frac{k^2+1}{2}$$ respectively when $k$ is odd

$$2k,k^2-1,k^2+1$$ respectively when $k$ is even

Comment: Not all Pythagorean triples fit these formulas.  For instance, the triple $(21, 20, 29)$ satisfies the equation $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ since $21^2 + 20^2 = 441 + 400 = 841 = 29^2$, but it does not fit the two formulas you described.  The general rule is that \begin{align*}a & = k(m^2 - n^2)\\ b & = k(2mn)\\ c & = k(m^2 + n^2)\end{align*} where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime positive integers of different parity (one is even and the other is odd) and $k$ is a positive integer.  For the triple $(21, 20, 29)$, take $k = 1$, $m = 5$, and $n = 2$.

Comment: You can adjust your answer to account for this information.  Note that $b$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

We know , a,b,c are integers.
Now some basic principles:

odd number +another odd number=even number.

Odd + even = odd.

even+even = even .

These 3 relations hold true for all integers.

We also know that square of and odd integer is odd, similarly square of an even integer is even.

So now if see the equation  a²+b²=c², we can conclude:

*If both 'a' and 'b' are odd , then the above sum is even , therefore 'c' must be even.

*If one of 'a' and 'b' is odd and other is even, then the sum a²+b² is odd which means 'c' must be odd.

*If both 'a' and 'b' are even then 'c' must be even .

These 3 cases cover all the possibilities .

Now in any of these case, atleast 1 of the three integers is even and at most 2 can be odd, which means that the product 'abc' is ALWAYS EVEN.

Thank you.
--Class 12th student as of 2020

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score -2):

Suppose $a$, $b$, and $c$ are odd. Then $a=2p-1$, $b=2q-1$, and $c=2r-1$. Inserting these into our formula, $a^2+b^2=c^2$, we get $(2p-1)^2+(2q-1)^2=(2r-1)^2$. Expanding, $4p^2-2p+1+4q^2-2q+1=4r^2-2r+1$, or $4p^2-2p+4q^2-2q+1=4r^2-2r$.

When written as $2(2p^2-p+2q^2-q+1)-1$, we see that the LHS is odd. Likewise, we see that the RHS is even. Because we can never have a value that is both even and odd, we get a contradiction. We can then say one of $a$, $b$, or $c$ must be even.

Let's say that $a$ is even; then $a=2n$, and $abc=2nbc$. We see that $abc$ is even. The other two cases are similar.

Therefore, we can say that $abc$ is even, in general.